# Bind Collection of USercontrol to Stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am currently working on Wpf application.
I have a usercontrol called SearchFilters.I want to bind the collection of usercontrol to mainWindow's stackpanel's children,means want to put all that usercontrols as a childrens of stackpanel.How can I achieve that ?
Please help !

Comment: If you have multiple instances of the same UserControl class, use an ItemsControl and put the UserControl in its `ItemTemplate`. In this DataTemplate, bind the UserControl's properties to the properties of your view model item class.

Comment: actually I am new to WPF,can you give me an example of it.Thanks.@Clemens

Comment: I have only one Usercontrol and I want to make a list of that usercontrol instances and want to bind that list to stackpanel's children.

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx). Pay special attention to the [Styling and Templating an ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx#DataTemplating_ItemsControl) section.

Answer (score 1):

try this, in MainWindow

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourBindableCollection}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:YourUserControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**YourUserControl** must be in same folder as MainWindow if you wish to keep **local** as namespace

Comment: Why a ListView? There was no mention in the question that items should be selectable or might be displayed as columns. You should replace ListView by ItemsControl. Also there is absolute no need that "YourUserControl must be in same folder as MainWindow". It only depends on how the XML namespace `local`is declared. The UserControl could as well be in a dífferent assembly.

Comment: @Clemens I agree, Listview can be replace by ItemsControl. In comment user said he is new to WPF so I specified the note in the last, because I used namespace local.